# Иду через город

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли так говорить или надо уточнять: «Иду через весь город»?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно можно так сказать. Даже не совсем понятно, какие причины для сомнений. Если хотите подчеркнуть, что идти далеко, то лучше сказать "через весь город". Примеры из литературы:

> Я **иду через город** и только теперь обращаю внимание на то, как много
>   здесь церквей, которые чертят своими крестами быстро бегущие облака.
>   (Н.Асанов)
>
> После всей маяты **иду через весь город** на Покровскую... (Корней
>   Чуковский)

Answer (score 2):

**весь**, всего, м.; ж. **вся**, всей; ср. **всё**, всего; мн. **все**, всех;  местоимение.
**2.** 1)
а) Целый, полный; без остатка.
**б) От начала до конца.**
[**Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка**](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)

*Вот **через площадь мы идем**

И входим наконец

В большой, красивый красный дом,

Похожий на дворец.*
С. Михалков

*Десантники **прошли через снежную пустыню** Северного полюса, передвигаясь на снегоступах и лыжах.

Линия **прошла через посёлок**, и здесь соорудили ж/д станцию Рокитное.

В рамках марафона «от Москвы до Пекина» **через город Владимир пробежал** путешественник Александр Капер.*

Если Вам хочется сделать акцент на том, что путь через территорию был особенным (длинным, трудным, тяжелым) или пролегал "насквозь" (не краем), тогда стоит добавить уточнение "весь":
иду через *весь* город, прошли через *всю* снежную пустыню, прошла через *весь* посёлок.